# Waiting time distribution parameters given expected mean

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, modeling

I have a set of healthcare providers serving patients. In a given amount of time, a specific provider can see only a certain amount of patients, depending on the medical procedure and other variables.

A patient, since the booking of the procedure, is seen by the doctor after a certain amount of days, again specific to provider, procedure etc...

I have a data set in which for each provider, for a given amount of time, I know how many patients have been seen and what was the average waiting time. 
I want to simulate more patients for each provider and their individual waiting times.

I assumed that the number of patients seen in the given time can be modeled as a $\sim Poisson(\lambda)$ with lambda depending on provider and procedure characteristics and amount of time.

I modeled the average waiting time as $\sim lognormal(\mu_{global}, \sigma)$ with parameters as a function of the same variables of before plus the log of n.patients.

Finally, I'm modeling the simulated new patients waiting time as $\sim Gamma((\mu/SD)^2, SD^2/\mu)$ with $\mu$ predicted from the model above and $SD$ chosen using domain knowledge since I don't have past information on individual waiting times.

I would like to know if I choose the right distributions given the problem at hand.

Comment: The number of patients seen in the given time cannot be modeled as Poisson — this is not a Poisson process because the events are not independent of each other. If a provider sees one patient, it becomes much more unlikely they will see the next because they have to spend time with the patient. In other words, the time between events cannot be modeled by an exponential distribution.  Instead, time between events should be modeled as a gamma distribution where $ k\theta \approx 20 $ (if 20min is the average time spent seeing a patient).

Comment: Moreover, could you please explain the derivation of $\lambda$ with respect to $Poisson(\lambda)$

Comment: wait wait. This is not a queueing system, in which patients are seen in the same order in which they book. I can get my visit booked in urgency (less than one day) or months from today. Then there is the personnel at each provider (can be more than one doctor). Providers always keep some room for unseen visits that are more urgent. Furthermore operators move patients up and down (with no clear criteria sometime). Therefore I thought about treating the patients as independent, with a different Poisson process for each situation (providere, procedure, emergency class) with a different $\lambda$.

Comment: Then, maybe I wasn't clear, but I don't have individual patient data, I only got the average waiting time for a certain amount of patients seen in a certain amount of time of provider activity (ie. 4 and 12 months)

Comment: still sounds not Poisson to me because the waiting time would be Gamma where $\mu >\approx 10$ as opposed to exponential.

Comment: Can you explain better your last statement?

Comment: I edited the question because my parametrization of Gamma was wrong.

Comment: the time between two events in a Poisson process is an exponential distribution. The time between two patients would not be an exponential distribution, but would probably look more Gamma. Therefore, this is not a Poisson process.

Comment: I changed my model, using gamma instead of log normal for the distribution of the mean waiting times, thank you. About the number of people, if not Poisson then, how should I describe it? for now I switched to negative binomial, to account for overdispersion (the predicted numbers with Poisson were too much concentrated).

Comment: Not negative binomial distribution either. This does not involve a Bernoulli experiment.

Comment: What would you suggest then?

Answer (score 4):

It is best to look at the distribution of waiting times for a particular provider. My first thought would be that if the process is anything like a queueing If  process that the distribution should be nearly exponential. So I would check to see if the sample mean and standard deviation are approximately equal. If so, I would look to see if an empirical CDF (ECDF) of the data
roughly fits the CDF of $\mathsf{Exp}(\text{rate} = \lambda),$ where $\mu = 1/\lambda$ is estimated as $\hat \mu = \bar X,$ the sample mean.

Only if that doesn't seem to work well, would I pursue fitting the data to a gamma distribution. This is also a plausible possibility, partly because the sum of $k$ exponential waiting times (of the same rate) is gamma-distributed with shape parameter $k.$ [If you use a 'distribution ID' program, a 'gamma' distribution will almost always win out over 'exponential' because the family $\mathsf{Exp}$ is a sub-family of $\mathsf{Gamma}.$]

**Exponential data.** As an initial example, let's pursue data randomly sampled from $\mathsf{Exp}(\text{rate} = 1/10),$ so that the average waiting time is (a perhaps optimistic) 10 days. Suppose we
have waiting times for $n = 500$ patients.

```
set.seed(714)       # for reproducibility
x = rexp(500, 0.1)
mean(x);  sd(x)
[1] 9.909112
[1] 10.36662
```

So the sample mean and SD are about the same. In practice, I would not know
the true rate $\lambda$ so I will estimate it as $\hat \lambda = 1/9.9 = 0.101.$

In the plot below, the boxplot shows many high 'outliers', as is typical of
an exponential sample. The Density function of $\mathsf{Exp}(0.101),$ is a
reasonable fit to the histogram of the data. Also (usually more revealing),
the ECDF plot of the sample is well-approximated by the CDF of this distribution. [The ECDF is a 'stairstep' plot that jumps up by $1/500$ at each of the $500$ observed
values.]

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
boxplot(x, col="skyblue2", pch=19, main="Boxplot of DATA")
hist(x, prob=T, br=20, col="skyblue2", main="Histogram with EXP(.101) Density")
 rug(x); curve(dexp(x, .101), add=T, col="red")
plot(ecdf(x), main="ECDF with EXP(.101) CDF")
 curve(pexp(x, .101), add=T, col="red")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

These favorable results are hardly surprising because data were sampled from an exponential population. If real data performs as well, then you could simulate additional data from a similar population with R code `rexp(n, 0.101)`, where parameter `n` is the desired number of simulated values.

However, you must realize that you are not gaining additional information about actual patient waiting times by doing that. All the 'information' you have is given by the sample and the assumption that the population is exponential.

**Gamma data.** If the exponential model does not seem to fit, perhaps the next step is to assume that data are gamma-distributed, to estimate the parameters, and make similar plots to see if you get a better fit to the data.
[Several pages on this site and online discuss estimation of gamma
parameters; one recent [page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/417005/how-do-i-get-the-cdf-of-a-gamma-distribution-with-mean-and-sd/417035#417035) discusses both MMEs and MLEs.]

Just to see what happens if we have gamma data and try to fit an exponential model, I repeat the simulation above, but using `x = rgamma(500, 2, .2)`.

```
set.seed(714) # for reproducibility
x = rgamma(500, 2, 0.2)
mean(x); var(x)
[1] 10.62662
[1] 59.49749
```

Pretending that these data are exponential and estimating the rate as
$\hat \lambda = 0.1062,$ R code similar to that above gives the following
graphs--with noticeably unsatisfactory fits.

[image]

Using a gamma model with method-of-moments estimators (MMEs) from the link above, I estimate
the shape parameter as $\hat \alpha = 1.90$ and the rate parameter as
$\hat \lambda = 0.178.$ [Maximum likelihood estimators (MLEs) would likely be
more accurate, but MMEs are good enough to give an idea how the graphing procedure works.]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate and formative answer! I need to be sure we are on the same page here: your answer was about modeling the average waiting time per provider isn't it? not the single patient wating time. Because I got only the first as data, while the second (my goal) are to be simulated based only on theoretical information (is this or that distribution good for that process?).

Comment: Furthermore I'm afraid I cannot even replicate your analysis on the average watiting times, because it would be wrong to assume that distribution parameters are the same for each context (provider, procedure, urgency, etc). That's why I used a hierarchical model in which I model the average waiting time as from lognormal (is it ok?) distributions whose parameter (eg. $\mu_{global}$) are predicted from the context characteristics. Therefore in my data there's a lot more variance than what to expect from canonical distributions.
I don't know if I explained myself.

Comment: I think you need to try to understand the distributions of waiting times for individual providers first. Then you might be able to simulate individual patient waiting times depending on provider, diagnosis, and so on. Not knowing whether waiting times for different providers are even governed by the same distribution families, I don't see how you can make sense out of a more comprehensive model. // I don't understand your rationale for using the lognormal distribution. Perhaps that is useful as an overall descriptive tactic, but I don't see how it can help modeling for individual patients.

Comment: I also have doubts about the use of lognormal to describe the distribution of the average waiting times, that's one of the things I need help with. About the distribution of the individual waiting times, since I do not have that data, I was asking if Gamma can be "theoretically" correct given the problem. It's like choosing a prior not on parameters, but on the distribution shape itself, albeit not having data to change that prior.