# Which likelihood function is correct?

Tags: probability, bayesian, likelihood, queueing

I have a confusion related to the likelihood function. I suppose that users waiting time $W$ follows an Exp distribution with the rate $\lambda$, and the prior of $\lambda$ follows Gamma($\alpha$, $\beta$). We have the information that after the user has waited for 5 min, he still needs to wait for another 10min. But, I am confused that if I want to use this information to make bayesian updating on the waiting time, should it be
$$P(\lambda|D)=P(X=5+10|X\geqslant 5) \times  P(X\geqslant 5)\times P(\lambda)=P(X=5+10)\times P(\lambda)$$ or $$P(\lambda|D)=P(X=5+10|X\geqslant 5)\times P(\lambda)$$ or other.

Comment: Here's a [related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/417425).